# Istio on GKE is not working (Connection refused)

Tags: service, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, gateway

I'm currently try to setup a Istio on my GKE cluster for some test. But I don't know why my setup is not working... When I try to use http port to check my service nothing appear `Connection refused`. But the port `15021` is working with a blank page.

I install Istio with this helm command:

```bash
kubectl create namespace istio-system
helm install istio-base istio/base -n istio-system --set defaultRevision=default
helm install istiod istio/istiod -n istio-system --wait
kubectl create namespace istio-ingress
helm install istio-ingress istio/gateway -n istio-ingress --wait --values=values.yaml
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled --overwrite
```

And after I just apply this files:

*my-deployment.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

*my-service.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: istio-ingress
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

*my-virtualservice.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

*my-gateway.yaml*

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

I try to remove the https port from the Istio ingress install but it's still broken.

Some screens:

[image: Deployment]
*(Don't worry about the ip, the cluster will be destroyed.)*
[image: Service]